# rosrun beginner_tutorials listener.py results in no output

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI All

I'm using ubuntu 16/04 along with python for writing nodes.

I just have few hours experience on ROS.

I pushed rosrun beginner_tutorials listener.py after defining the source but this resulted in no output ust the cursor blinking for few times then stagnant.

I rechecked the CMakeLists.txt but couldn't find any any dependencies in it with reference to tutorials (**I'm not sure though**)

Sincerely

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277559/rosrun-beginner_tutorials-listener.py-results-in-no-output/) by [shivak singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32903/shivak-singh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming that you're doing the [subscriber/publisher tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29)  for rospy. Are you running the talker node? The listener node will only do something if there's a node publishing (i.e.,callback functions are only called when they receive data on a topic). Try running both nodes and see what happens.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [okkewei](https://answers.ros.org/users/60420/okkewei/) on 2020-10-14**:
To add-on, run another terminal (e.g: control +shift + o) and rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to publish the topic what you have configured for subscribing. If the topic is not being published, your subscriber callback function is not called.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2